# How to reduce runtime for for loop statements in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a program that is taking over 2 minutes to run and I'm not sure what I could do to reduce the runtime. It's most definitely the for loop shown in the code.

```
"CPU Start Address in decimal"
CPU_START_ADDR = 1644167168 #0x62000000

"Import necessary libraries"
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

"Creates variable for time to display runtime"
start_time = time.time()

"Create a blank dataframe with necessary column headers"
columnNames = ["Settings 1 Values", "Settings 2 Values", "CPU Address", "FPGA Address", "Delta (Decimal)", "Delta (Pos. Difference)", "Register Name", "R/W"]
output = pd.DataFrame(columns = columnNames)


"Fill values from settings files into output dataframe"
df1 = pd.read_csv("50MHzWholeFPGA.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("75MHzWholeFPGA.csv")
spec = pd.read_excel("Mozart FPGA Register Specification.xlsx", skiprows=[0,1,2,3])
output.loc[:, "Settings 1 Values"] = df1.iloc[:, 0]
output.loc[:, "Settings 2 Values"] = df2.iloc[:, 0]
output['Delta (Decimal)'] = output['Settings 2 Values'] - output['Settings 1 Values']

"For loop generates CPU Addresses for all values"
for index, row in output.iterrows():
    output.loc[index, 'CPU Address'] = hex(CPU_START_ADDR + (2 * index))[2:]
    settingXor = bin(int(output.loc[index, "Settings 1 Values"]) ^ int(output.loc[index, "Settings 2 Values"]))
    output.loc[index, "Delta (Pos. Difference)"] = settingXor
```

Comment: what have you tried? have you timed the loop separately to make sure it is the slow part of the code?

Comment: Where is your end_time? How big is output? You are using .loc many times which is a O(N) algorithm.

Comment: Perhaps I'm way off base here not being a python expert but wouldn't `for index, row in output[output["CPU Address"]= hex(CPU_StART_ADDR + (2*index))[2:]]` be quicker (Assuming you only have a fraction of rows in your dataframe for which the `CPU Address` matches that hex).

Comment: Probably don;t loop in the first place and use vectorized operations

Comment: What exactly would I need to do for vectorized operations? I am a little new to this